# Aggregate not behaving in Meteor as in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, meteor, aggregation-framework

This is the query that I'm trying to run. If I run it on the Mongo console I get

```
meteor:PRIMARY> db.keywords_o2m.aggregate({$match:{keyword:{$in:['sql']}}},{$unwind:'$synonym'},{$group:{_id:0,kw:{$addToSet:'$synonym'}}});
{ "_id" : 0, "kw" : [ "database" ] }
```

However, if I copypaste it and try to run it on Meteor calling `Meteor.call('getAllKeywordSynonyms',kw,function(err,data){...});` with this code

```
if(Meteor.isServer){
    Meteor.methods({
        'getAllKeywordSynonyms':function(keyword){
            console.log("keywordO2M aggregate");
            console.log(keywordO2M.aggregate({$match:{keyword:{$in:['sql']}}},{$unwind:'$synonym'},{$group:{_id:0,kw:{$addToSet:'$synonym'}}}));
        }
    )};
}
```

I get

```
I20151220-12:49:38.197(-8)? keywordO2M aggregate
I20151220-12:49:38.197(-8)? [ { _id: 5676fe5a17aeddb799dc4ef8,
I20151220-12:49:38.197(-8)?     keyword: 'sql',
I20151220-12:49:38.197(-8)?     synonym: 'database' } ]
```

It looks like it ran the $match and ignored the $unwind and $group.

I've tried using `meteorhacks:aggregate` and `monbro:mongod-mapreduce-aggregation`, but no difference.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meteor is not as forgiving with notation.

With the aggregation function, the pipeline stages need to all be passed as a single parameter in an array, so the correct syntax would be

```
console.log(keywordO2M.aggregate([{$match:{keyword:{$in:['sql']}}},{$unwind:'$synonym'},{$group:{_id:0,kw:{$addToSet:'$synonym'}}}]));
```

Note the square brackets so that only one parameter gets passed to aggregate.